# White space appearing after browser resize

Tags: html, css

On my current project I am in the process of building tablet and mobile versions of the site and am testing it within the browser at the different sizes, though I am coming across a problem when resizing the browser.

The current version of the site can be found at: http://beta.residencyradio.com

Basically whenever I resize the browser to check how it will look on the tablet for example, white space is rendered to the right and the x scrollbar appears, even though the width of the containing element has not been exceeded.

I can pretty much solve the issue by adding `overflow: hidden` but this disables x scrolling completely, which I don't want.

I have tested this across all major browsers, all respond the same, so it must be to do with the CSS, what exactly I'm not too sure, but it's probably something very simple that I've managed to miss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Michael

Comment: Cool site, reminds me of http://www.adaptly.com

Comment: thanks dude, never actually seen that site before, I must be on the same brainwave as their designer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That whitespace is being created because your `#second` div is being pushed outside the boundaries of the viewport. Instead of pushing that div using `margin-left`, use `position:absolute;` in its place to fix that issue.

This is how it is now:

```
#second .content {
    margin-left: 22.8125em;
}
```

The `.content` div has a width of `60em` as it is.

You can use something like this instead and it should work fine:

```
#second .content {
    left: 170px; /* adjust to your liking */
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Indeed it is! Don't know how I didn't spot that! Thanks amigo, you the man.

Answer (score 0):

I think....

change in your css file:

from:

```
html {
font-size: 16px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background: url("../images/bkgMAIN.jpg") repeat-y;
}
```

to

```
html {
font-size: 16px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background: url("../images/bkgMAIN.jpg") repeat-y;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

It looks like that image (with the cool gradient) isn't stretching horizontally when the page is zoomed out

Is this it?

Comment: thanks for the reply dude, unfortunately this doesn't work :( It still renders the white space at the side, therefore making the x scrollbar appear. Something is rendering this white space, and I've no idea what :/

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

And it removed the weird whitespacing while also allowing to scroll in the x-direction.

Answer (score 0):

I usually fix it with

```
 html {
  overflow-x:hidden;  
 }
```

It should work and hide the white space and rescale the site

Answer (score 0):

Tried

```
html {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

didn't work. But..

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Did.